Displaying external thumbnails for virtual posts without uploading to WordPress media library
I am developing a plugin for WordPress that dynamically adds virtual posts recalled from an external API to the post overview on the front page. The front page typically displays the post_title, post_excerpt, post_date, author, and a thumbnail for each post in an overview.
My issue: While I am able to display the post_title, post_excerpt, and post_date for the virtual posts, I am unable to inject the external thumbnail for the virtual posts. It seems WordPress requires the post to have an actual ID and for the images to be uploaded to the WordPress media library for the thumbnail to work correctly (it obviously takes the basic post data and then looks for image data in the own database instead of taking the external link). However, I need to display external images as thumbnails without uploading them to the media library, as a dynamic upload would slow down the page load and copyright issues may arise.
What I've tried:
Using add_filter('post_thumbnail_html'...) to override the thumbnail HTML:
add_filter('post_thumbnail_html', function ($html, $post_id, $post_thumbnail_id, $size, $attr) {
    global $post;

    if (isset($post->is_virtual) && $post->is_virtual) {
        $html = '<img src="' . esc_url($post->primaryImage) . '" class="wp-post-image" />';
    }

    return $html;
}, 10, 5);

Updating the metadata of the virtual posts:
add_filter('get_post_metadata', function ($meta_value, $object_id, $meta_key, $single) {
    global $post;

    if (isset($post->ID) && $post->is_virtual && $meta_key === '_thumbnail_id') {
        return $post->primaryImage;
    }

    return $meta_value;
}, 99, 4);

update_post_meta($post->ID, 'featured_image', $article['primaryImage']);
update_post_meta($post->ID, '_thumbnail_id', $article['primaryImage']);
update_post_meta($post->ID, 'custom_image_url', $article['primaryImage']);

None of these attempts have worked for displaying the external images as thumbnails in the post overview.
Is there any way to add a thumbnail to virtual posts using external images, without creating a post ID and uploading those images to the WordPress media library? How can I get WordPress to display the external image as the thumbnail for these virtual posts?

What function are you using to attempt to show the thumnbnail? Is it get_the_post_thumbnail or wp_get_attachment_image or something else? Depending on which you use, you might have to change the theme itself since, as you noted, the core functions usually expect a valid post ID to exist in the first place.

Here’s what I’ve tried:
get_the_post_thumbnail(): This function requires a valid post_id to retrieve the featured image, which doesn’t work for virtual posts that aren’t stored in the database.
wp_get_attachment_image(): Similar to get_the_post_thumbnail, it expects an actual attachment ID or post ID, and thus doesn’t work for virtual posts either.
Filters (post_thumbnail_html, get_post_metadata): I’ve tried intercepting these filters to manually insert external images, but since the theme doesn’t trigger the thumbnail functions for virtual posts, these filters don’t seem to apply.

Sound like you just need to update the template to test if the post is virtual, and if so, do custom stuff, and if not, do core stuff. if(property_exists($post, 'is_virtual') && $post->is_virtual) { get_virtual_post_thumbnail_image($post); } else { get_the_post_thumbnail(); }. You could add that literally to the template, or make a wrapper function`

So, I finally got it working by faking a negative thumbnail_id in get_post_metadata. Without, it searched for the image in the media library. Also, I had to change the fake negative post_id into a positive id (i.e. 90001 to prevent conflicts)... this finally made the trick for me...
